# How to calculate the time delay of a signal by a first-order filter

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, phase, delay

lets assume following signal
$$x=a_1 \sin(2\pi f_1 t) + a_2 \sin(2\pi f_2 t).$$
This is passed through a simple single-pole filter with cut-off frequency $f_c$. How is $x$ delayed by the filter (peak of the cross-correlation)?

In the case $a_2=0$, the time delay between the original and the filtered frequency is 
$$T_1=\arctan(f_1/f_c)/(2\pi f_1).$$

In the case $a_1=0$, the time delay between the original and the filtered frequency is 
$$T_2=\arctan(f_2/f_c)/(2\pi f_2).$$

But how can we calculate the time delay $T_{12}$ in the case $a_1\neq0$ and $a_2\neq0$?

It is not the group delay: It must depend in some way on the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$, because if $a_1>>a_2$, then $T_{12}\approx T_1$.

Any light on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the output signal for the case $a_1\neq 0$ and $a_2\neq 0$ is not simply a delayed version of the input signal anymore, as it would be if the input were just a single sinusoid. With $T_1$ and $T_2$ as given in your question, the response to the combined input signal is

$$y(t)=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{1+(f_1/f_c)^2}}\sin(2\pi f_1(t-T_1))+\frac{a_2}{\sqrt{1+(f_2/f_c)^2}}\sin(2\pi f_2(t-T_2))$$

which cannot be written as $x(t-T_x)$ with some unknown delay $T_x$.

But as you suggested, you could define some 'global delay' by the first maximum of the cross-correlation between the input signal and the output signal. This cross-correlation is

$$R_{xy}(\tau)=\frac{a_1^2}{2\sqrt{1+(f_1/f_c)^2}}\cos(2\pi f_1(\tau-T_1))+\\+
\frac{a_2^2}{2\sqrt{1+(f_2/f_c)^2}}\cos(2\pi f_2(\tau-T_2))\tag{1}$$

For $a_2=0$, there is obviously a maximum of $R_{xy}(\tau)$ at $\tau=T_1$. The same is true for $a_1=0$, which gives $\tau=T_2$ as the location of the maximum. However, for $a_1\neq 0$ and $a_2\neq 0$ I don't see how to compute the first maximum of (1) analytically. A numerical solution is of course possible.

Comment: Thanks Matt. But when we calculate the cross correlation, the peak will be somewhere between $T_1$ and $T_2$. Is there no analytic solution to find that peak?
Btw, shouldn't the new amplitudes be $1/\sqrt(1+f_1^2/f_c^2)$ ?

Comment: @AnkaiosArgo: Thanks for pointing out the magnitudes, I was just focusing on the delays. Fixed it. I'll need to think about what you say about the cross-correlation.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be picky :-) Would be great, if you find a solution... In order to find the peak in the cross-correlation, maybe we can calculate the cross-spectra?

Comment: @AnkaiosArgo: I added some info about cross-correlation to my answer. Unfortunately, I can't see how to find an analytical solution.

Comment: Thanks, this already helps... would you mind to elaborate, how you determined the $R_{xy}(\tau)$? The auto-correlation of a sum of sinus is a sum of cosines, see e.g. http://www.chem.purdue.edu/courses/chm621/lecture/electronics/8.6%20Autocorrelation.pdf , but in the case of the cross-correlation and the time-shift $T_i$ it does not seems very trivial to me.

Comment: @AnkaiosArgo: In this case the cross-correlation is almost the same as the autocorrelation because the output signal is just a weighted and shifted version of the input (for each sinusoidal component). So you basically get the autocorrelation function (sum of cosines) with different weighting factors and shifts of $T_i$. The cross-products (with different frequencies) are all zero.